# Find these moments?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

[image]

I'm just looking for guidance with a, I haven't attempted b yet. Here's my work for a:

Let $Z=\xi_1+...+\xi_N$. This is an assumption so I doubt it's accurate but since $P(\xi=\pm1)=\frac{1}{2}$ suggests the possibility of a binomial distribution, since this would allow for a heads-or-tails-type probability decision.

If that's the case, then I would consider $E[\xi_i]=Np=\mu$ and $Var[\xi_i]=Np(1-p)=\sigma^2$. 
Since $p_N(n)$ follows a geometric distribution, $E[N]=\frac{1}{p}=v$ and $Var[N]=\frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha^2}=\tau^2$ (Note: the nomenclature chosen is from Pinsky's *An Introduction to Stochastic Modeling*.)

Then, $E[Z]=\mu v=\frac{Np}{p}=N$ and $Var[Z]=v\sigma^2+\mu^2\tau^2=N(1-p)+\frac{(Np)^2(1-\alpha)}{\alpha^2}$.

I'm very new to all of this, the last probability course I had was in undergrad and it didn't really include statistics. I took an applied statistical methodology graduate course last term and did well. This is a grad independent study in stochastic modeling. Would someone please help direct my attempt?

Comment: notice that $\xi_i$ can take negative values so it is clearly not a binomial distribution. Better to simply use the definition $\mathbb{E}[\xi_i] = (-1)\cdot \mathbb{P}(\xi_i = -1) + 1\cdot \mathbb{P}(\xi_i = 1) = 0$.

Comment: It's also not a Binomial since the number of terms, $N$, is not constant. (If $N$ were constant, then it'd be a shifted, rescaled Binomial)

Comment: Thanks, @LeanderTilstedKristensen and Clement C. That makes a lot of sense, I totally overlooked the possibility of -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, *conditioned on $N$*, it is a rescaled, shifted Binomial distribution (note that the summands are in $\{-1,1\}$, not $\{0,1\}$). Unfortunately, $N$ is a random variable as well, so you cannot really do that immediately.

What you *can* do, however, is use the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation):
$$
\mathbb{E}[Z] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Z\mid N]] \tag{1}
$$
As you noticed, $\mathbb{E}[Z\mid N] = 0$ (it's a shifted Binomial!), so that gives you
$$
\mathbb{E}[Z] = 0
$$
which you can now compute from the probability mass function of $N$.

Now, for the variance, there is a [law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance) you can similarly use, but since you also will want the third and fourth moments as well, we may look at a useful rewriting of $Z$:
$$
Z = \sum_{k=1}^N \xi_k = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \xi_k \mathbf{1}_{N \geq k}
\tag{2}$$
This is useful, as by assumption $\xi_k$ and $\mathbf{1}_{N \geq k}$ are independent for all $k$. For instance, if we wanted to re-derive the expectation of $Z$:
$$
\mathbb{E}[Z] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb{E}[\xi_k \mathbf{1}_{N \geq k}]
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb{E}[\xi_k]\cdot \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{N \geq k}]
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty 0\cdot \mathbb{P}\{{N \geq k}\}= 0\,.
$$
We retrieve the result. But now, also,
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[Z^2] = \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \xi_k \mathbf{1}_{N \geq k}\right)^2\right]
= \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty \xi_k\xi_\ell \mathbf{1}_{N \geq k}\mathbf{1}_{N \geq \ell}\right]\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty \mathbb{E}\left[\xi_k\xi_\ell]\cdot\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{N \geq k}\mathbf{1}_{N \geq \ell}\right]
\end{align}$$
However, now we have that $\mathbb{E}[\xi_k\xi_\ell] = 1$ if $\ell=k$, and $0$ if $\ell\neq k$ *(by independence and since $\xi_k^2=1$; can you see why?)*, so the above expression for the variance simplifies a lot to 
$$
\operatorname{Var} Z = \mathbb{E}[Z^2] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{N \geq k}] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\mathbb{P}\{N \geq k\} = \mathbb{E}[N]\,.
$$
The third and fourth moments can be done similarly, though it gets longer.

Comment: Thanks for the visual illustration with infinite sums, this makes a lot of sense. Having just completed a course in complex analysis this is very familiar.

Comment: @Strakatastic You're welcome!